# Microservices Pattern - Downstream Services Registering Themselves with an Upstream Orchestrator?

Tags: microservices, architectural-patterns

I'm looking for some guidance on a design proposition I have to accomplish the following use case:

- We have several small microservices that each generate a unique set of "**analytics**" or **attributes** about a customer
- We want a consolidated interface for partners to request each set of analytics, e.g. via a **REST** call `POST /analytics-sets/{set-id}`
- We want partners to be able to define a **custom report template** that combines any combination of attributes from the downstream microservices

We have a generic reporting engine that all of this will be sitting under, which is what our partner will actually interact with.

My proposition is as follows:

- Create a sort of orchestrator or gateway service that pulls the attributes from all the downstream microservices
- Rather than hardcoding the `set-id` to `microservice-X` mapping or using a static config file, have the downstream services "register" themselves with the orchestrator when they are deployed with some startup logic (creates a new attribute set available to discover from the orchestrator's API)

My rationale is that this eliminates the need to make changes to the orchestrator codebase when new sets of attributes are available, but I can't find anything from Google searching if others have attempted this pattern to find other pros/cons I might not be considering.

Do you think this is a viable approach? I am open to other suggestions as well. Appreciate any response.

P.S. We cannot use **GraphQL** for this as we do not have the ability to expose this publicly to our partners.

Comment: How does the concept of a `set-id` mapping to a single microservice match with the requirement that a single report from a call to `POST /analytics-sets/{set-id}` combines results from multiple microservices?

Comment: The client needs to be able to either request one of these predefined sets, OR they can specify any number of attributes from any number of sets. The orchestrator would manage knowing where to pull each requested attribute from

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think this is a viable approach when using microservices.

One of the most basic ideas behind microservices is that each service can be deployed independently and scaled independently of the other services. This has the consequence that at any point in time, service instances of a particular service can be added or removed (either to deal with load fluctuations or because of a software update or any other reason).

This makes it really hard to maintain an accurate list of analytics services in each instance of your orchestrator services.

A better approach is to use a communication bus on which the orchestrator (or the report generator) asks for the value of an attribute and any service that knows about the attribute answers (possibly unless they have seen the answer come by already). The orchestrator then just uses the first answer they receive and discard the rest.

This way, the services only have to register to the bus and don't have to know about each other.

Comment: Something I failed to mention in the original post, is that the downstream microservices already have a requirement to expose their functionality over standard REST interfaces for other apps in the org to be able to use. 

This approach requires each one to accept inputs on twice as many channels.

Also, I would plan to store the config in a database or cache shared by instances of the orchestrator service